# MongoDB + K means clustering

Tags: python, mongodb, machine-learning, scikit-learn, nltk

I'm using MongoDB as my datastore and wish to store a "clustered" configuration of my documents in a separate collection.

So in one collection, I'd have my original set of objects, and in my second, it'd have

```
kMeansCollection: {
     1: [mongoObjectCopy1], [mongoObjectCopy2]...
     2: [mongoObjectCopy3], [mongoObjectCopy4]... 
   }
```

I'm following the implementation a K-means for text clustering here, http://tech.swamps.io/recipe-text-clustering-using-nltk-and-scikit-learn/, but I'm having a hard time thinking about how I'd tie the outputs back into MongoDB.

An example (taken from the link):

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    tags = collection.find({}, {'tag_data': 1, '_id': 0})
    clusters = cluster_texts(tags, 5) #algo runs here with 5 clusters
    pprint(dict(clusters))
```

The var "tags" is the required input for the algo to run. 
It must be in the form of an array, but currently tags returns an array of objects (I must therefore extract the text values from the query)

However, after magically clustering my collection 5 ways, how can I reunite  them with their respective object entry from mongo?

I am only feeding specific text content from one property of the object.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need to have some identifier for the documents. It is probably a good idea to include the `_id` field in your query so that you do have a unique document identifier. Then you can create parallel lists of `ids` and `tag_data`.

```
docs = collection.find({}, {'tag_data': 1, '_id': 1})
ids = [doc['_id'] for doc in docs]
tags = [doc['tag_data'] for doc in docs]
```

Then call the cluster function on the tag data.

```
clusters = cluster_text(tags)
```

And `zip` the results back with the `ids`.

```
doc_clusters = zip(ids, clusters)
```

From here you have built tuples of `(_id, cluster)` so you can update the cluster labels on your mongo documents.

Answer (score 1):

The efficient way to do this is to use the aggregation framework to create the list of "_id" and "tag-data" using server-side operation. This also reduces both the amount of data sent over the wire and the time and memory used to decode documents on the client-side.

You need to [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) your documents and use the [`$push`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/push/) accumulator operator to return the list of `_id` and the list of `tag-data`. Of course the [`aggregate()`](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.aggregate) method gives access to the aggregation pipeline.

```
cursor = collection.aggregate([{
    '$group': {
        '_id': None, 
        'ids': {'$push': '$_id'}, 
        'tags': {'$push': '$tag-data'}
    }
}])
```

You then retrieve you data using the [`.next()`](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/command_cursor.html#pymongo.command_cursor.CommandCursor.next) method on the [`CommandCursor`](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/command_cursor.html#pymongo.command_cursor.CommandCursor) because we group by `None` thus our cursor hold one element.

```
data = cursor.next()
```

After that, simply call your function and [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#zip) the result.

```
clusters = cluster_text(data['tags'])
doc_clusters = zip(data['ids'], clusters)
```